# How to store an image in MySQL database using REST webservice

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, rest, resteasy

I am working on a REST webservice,  I am  able store my image to mysql database as BLOB datatyepe.

Is there a way to give url of this image for client so they can access this image?

Answer (score 1):

As Eric mentioned, you can create an endpoint like you did to store the image that will return the image back to you. A summary of important steps may be:

Retrieve the blob from the database (for MySQL):

```
Blob imageBlob = rs.getBlob("file");
InputStream binaryStream = imageBlob.getBinaryStream(1, imageBlob.length());
```

Create the endpoint. You can return the InputStream as your entity:

```
@GET
@Path("/GetFile")
@Produces("application/octet-stream")
public Response getFile(@QueryParam("fileId") long fileId) {
    FileManager fileManager = new FileManager();

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = fileManager.getFileFromDB(fileId);

        return Response.ok(inputStream, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                  .build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
}
```

On the client-side, fetch. Here is a small sample from android where I return a Bitmap object back from my doInBackground of my AsyncTask (this need to be done in a background thread):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(<your_url_base>+"/GetFile?fileId=3"));
content = response.getEntity().getContent();
return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(content);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Write a separate endpoint that hits the database and responds with that image.